# Historic exchange rate sites show 0.0% on certain days for ZAR/AUD

Tags: foreign-exchange

From 2000/01/01 to the present, I have encountered 306 days over the years 2008, 2009 and 2010 that had a 0% change in the exchange rate on several sites that list historic exchange rate data.

As an example, 06 & 07 December 2008:

https://exchangerates.org/zar/aud/in-2008 (rates for those days are omitted)

https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php (0% change shown)

Screenshot from the freecurrencyapi.com API:
[API screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1Rg.png)

There are several other sites with the same ZAR/AUD results for those days, including an API.

Why does/did this happen? Could it perhaps be a data error that propagated because the sites conceivably obtained data from the same source?

P.S.: For my own purposes this is software development related. But the question is not. I am actually quite curious about this.

Comment: I presume these are days on which no exchange took place for one reason or another. 0/0 is undefined, and representing it as 0 is as good or bad as anything else.

Comment: Actually, I seem to remember that this question has been asked and answered before. Not finding it right now...